# Java use instanceof with iterator

Tags: java, iterator, polymorphism, instanceof

I have an abstract class `Usuario`and an `ArrayList<Usuario>` with objects of its three subclasses. I now want to iterate through the `ArrayList` and return a value depending of the result of using `instanceof` against that object.

I get an error: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

I suppose it is because of the iterator being an object of `Iterator` and not from any of the subclasses from `Usuario`. Am I right? is there any solution for that?

```
public int comprobarDni(String dniAComprobar, ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
    Iterator<Usuario> itUsuarios = listaUsuarios.iterator();
    while (itUsuarios.hasNext()) {
        if (dniAComprobar.equals(itUsuarios.next().getDni())) {
            if (itUsuarios.next() instanceof UsuarioBiblioteca) {
                return 1;
            } else if (itUsuarios.next() instanceof Bibliotecario) {
                return 2;
            } else if (itUsuarios.next() instanceof BibliotecaExterna) {
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `itUsuarios.next` multiple times during your iteration.

Therefore you might end up invoking it while the `List` has already been iterated fully, which will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Consider assigning a `Usuario` value once, and referring to that instead:

```
while (itUsuarios.hasNext()) {
  // reference this instead of itUsuarios.nex() for next references
  Usuario usuario = itUsuarios.next();
```

**Or...**

Go with fast enumeration for cleaner looking code:

```
for (Usuario usuario: listaUsuarios) {
    ...
```

Comment: Good answer, except the enhanced `for` loop is not "fast". It does the exact same thing, i.e. uses an iterator. It is simpler and cleaner code, but it is not faster code. Being simpler, it may be faster to write, but that's not how your text reads.

Comment: @Andreas if memory serves, "fast enumeration" here is just a synonym for "enhanced for loop". No claim on any performance improvement whatsoever. In fact, this idiom actually uses an Iterator behind the scenes... TL;DR faster to write, same performance.

Answer (score 4):

`Iterator.next()` returns the next item and advances the cursor. That's not what you want so try this instead:

```
Usuario usuario = itUsuarios.next();
...

if (usuario instanceof UsuarioBiblioteca) {
  return 1;
} else if (usuario instanceof Bibliotecario) {
   return 2;
} else if (usuario instanceof BibliotecaExterna) {
  return 3;
}
```

With your code consider the following case: `listaUsuarios` only contains two elements of type `BibliotecaExterna`. Your first call to `next()` will return the first element but since the type doesn't match you issue the second call to `next()` which returns the second element. Again the type doesn't match so you issue a third call to `next()` (`itUsuarios.next() instanceof BibliotecaExterna`) but *there is no third element* and hence you'll get the `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge misconception in your code:

If your current element is an instance of `BibliotecaExterna` it will call `next()` in the **first** if-statement and check it against `UsuarioBiblioteca`. But then the element has already changed.

Instead store it at the beginning:

```
Usuario element = itUsuarios.next();
if(element instance of ...)
...
```